# How to delete a non-empty directory with the find command on busybox?

Tags: find, delete-file, busybox

I want to delete certain directories matching a name pattern on a system running `busybox`, so I have [busybox `find`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/busybox.1.en#find) available to me.

For example if I want to delete all directories named `bar`, this command should work:

```bash
$ # Create the simplest possible example dirs:
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/baz
$ mkdir -p /tmp/quux/bar/baz
$
$ # Attempt to delete, but also print some debug info:
$ find /tmp/ -name bar -type d -exec sh -xc 'rm -rf "$1" && stat "$1"' -s {} \;
+ rm -rf /tmp/quux/bar
+ stat /tmp/quux/bar
stat: can't stat '/tmp/quux/bar': No such file or directory
find: /tmp/quux/bar: No such file or directory
+ rm -rf /tmp/foo/bar
+ stat /tmp/foo/bar
stat: can't stat '/tmp/foo/bar': No such file or directory
find: /tmp/foo/bar: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

As you can see:

- `find` finds the correct directory to delete.
- `rm -rf` is called on the correct directory.
- `stat` shows that it's successfully deleted.
- `find` FAILS, probably trying to further descend into the already deleted folder.

**How can I rewrite this operation to successfully complete?** The solution can only use busybox-based utilities, this is a constraint.

Comment: I have one solution on my own, ignoring the find command's result, but I don't like this solution as it might prevent me from seeing other issues with the find command.